# Is there any situation that we can get the primary key after savechanges from another method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

what I want to achieve is that I have a method that I want to get the primary key but the entity's primary key has not been filled after calling `SaveChange()` method.

Here is the controller:

```
public Add(string courseTitle) 
{
    var course = new courses()
                     {
                         Title = "mathematics"
                     }

    context.courses.add(course);

    int returnedId = ExternalSave(course);
}
```

And here is the service:

```
public int ExternalSave<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
{
    int result = 0;
    context.SaveChanges();
        
    result = entity.Id;

    return result;
}
```

But I couldn't get the primary key from this method.

Comment: Not enough information to help, could you please post more code like entity definition, table definition etc..? Also since it's a generic, how does the method know that there's an Id available in ExternalSave?

Comment: Its clear that i want to save generic models

Comment: Your code as it is, won't compile.

Comment: What's the purpose of this `ExternalSave` method? Why don't you just call `context.SaveChanges()`? It's not that it makes the code much longer or more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is the answer:

```
  var addedEntities = context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                 .Where(x => x.State ==EntityState.Added).FirstOrDefault();

  context.savechanges();

  return (int?)addedEntities.GetPropertyValue("Id");
```

Comment: no , after calling `savechanges()` method , the `Id` of the entity gets the value of it's table

Comment: You can get the `entry` for an entity like this `var id = (int?)db.Entry(entity).GetPropertyValue("Id");`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code first:

```
public Add(string courseTitle) 
{
    var course = new courses() { Title = courseTitle }
    context.courses.add(course);
    context.SaveChanges();

    int returnedId = course.Id;
}
```

The above code should populate `returnedId` ? If it does then there is something wrong with your service code.

Comment: thanks , I know it works in one method but i want to save logs of primary keys from saved records in another table.

Comment: Can you add this information to the question if it's stopping you accepting an answer

Answer (score 0):

one way is to return the Entity object back and then get the primary key property from it something like:

```
public TEntity ExternalSave<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
{
    context.SaveChanges();
              
    return entity;
}
```

and on the calling side like:

```
Course couse = ExternalSave(course);
int returnedKey = couse.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal generic way to do this is to introduce a base class for your entities that have `Id` as primary key, eg:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can constrain the generic method like this:

```
public int ExternalSave<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity: Entity
{
    this.SaveChanges();
    var id = entity.Id;
    return id;
}
```